# Is there a way to test 3<n<10 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators

In ruby is there a way to do the following

```
20.times do |n|
  if 3 < n < 10
    id = 40555
  end
end
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is `if n>3 and n<10 then id=40555`. There is a full Ruby syntax document at http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
20.times do |n|
  if 3 < n && n < 10
    id = 40555
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use two comparisons:

```
if 3 < n && n < 10
```

or you can use `between`:

```
if n.between? 3, 10
```

or you can use a range and the `cover?` (1.9) or `include?` (1.8) methods:

```
if (3..10).cover? n
```

Note though that the last two include the endpoints. A range can optionally exclude its endpoint though.

BTW, in a code review I'd flag "magic numbers" like the 3 and 10 as something that needs to be refactored into an appropriately named, self-documenting method, something like `if within_tolerance?(n)` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

```
n.between?(3, 10)
```

(Thanks to the humble [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) module)

Comment: _That_ was the one I was trying to remember! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good exercise to poke at the speed of various implementations.

For jollies I added the suggested code from the comment to the OP's question, which surprised me. I wouldn't have expected the change in the test to improve the speed, but it does make a minor difference. To understand why I added spaces, in case it was a line parsing issue, which I didn't think it would be. And, to rule out it was the `and` vs. `&&` operators I added those.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'

puts "Ruby #{ RUBY_VERSION }"

num_of_loops = 1000000

5.times do
  Benchmark.bm(10) do |benchmark|
    benchmark.report('<')        { num_of_loops.times { 3 < 4 && 4 < 10    } }
    benchmark.report('and')      { num_of_loops.times { 4>3 and 4<10       } }
    benchmark.report('and space'){ num_of_loops.times { 4 > 3 and 4 < 10   } }
    benchmark.report('&&')       { num_of_loops.times { 4>3 && 4<10        } }
    benchmark.report('between?') { num_of_loops.times { 4.between? 3, 10   } }
    benchmark.report('cover?')   { num_of_loops.times { (3..10).cover? 4   } }
    benchmark.report('include?') { num_of_loops.times { (4..9).include?(4) } }
  end
  puts
end

Ruby 1.9.2
                user     system      total        real
<           0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.237798)
and         0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.220596)
and space   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221239)
&&          0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221125)
between?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.589178)
cover?      0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.579952)
include?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.592481)

                user     system      total        real
<           0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.237692)
and         0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.220615)
and space   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221509)
&&          0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221178)
between?    0.600000   0.000000   0.600000 (  0.596799)
cover?      0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.579926)
include?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.594068)

                user     system      total        real
<           0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.237483)
and         0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.220532)
and space   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221618)
&&          0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.221055)
between?    0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.587682)
cover?      0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.579814)
include?    0.600000   0.000000   0.600000 (  0.593216)

                user     system      total        real
<           0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.238114)
and         0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.219626)
and space   0.220000   0.010000   0.230000 (  0.221149)
&&          0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221578)
between?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.589574)
cover?      0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.579924)
include?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.594782)

                user     system      total        real
<           0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.237504)
and         0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.220728)
and space   0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221041)
&&          0.220000   0.000000   0.220000 (  0.221258)
between?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.589589)
cover?      0.580000   0.000000   0.580000 (  0.579319)
include?    0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.591118)
```

In general the added spaces don't make a difference which is what I expected. The minor variance is probably due to some job firing on my machine.

Comment: Big O(f) wise, the implementations are the same, hence, the speed variation is statistically zero.  There's absolutely no performance reason to choose one over another, so use whatever makes the most legible code.

Comment: Actually in 1.9 `include?` iterates through the range and is O(n), which is why `cover?` was introduced. See http://rhnh.net/2009/08/03/range-include-in-ruby-1-9. I guess you'd see the difference in very large ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Not as clear as between 3 and 10 but still minimal.

```
20.times do |n|
  id = 40555 if (4..9).include?(n)
end
```